# How can I attach a PDF file stored as binary object in SQL Server to an email?

Tags: .net, sql-server, email, attachment, mailmessage

I'd like to attach a PDF file stored as binary object in SQL Server to an email but without creating a (temporary) file on disk.

I already have the first step to pull out the PDF file from the binary field in SQL Server as a `byte[]` array.

Also I have the step to setup the `MailMessage`:

```
MailMessage aMailMessage = new MailMessage();
// set address, subject, body
aMailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Where I am stuck is the `attachment` object:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(... what goes here? ...);
```

The constructor of `Attachment` accepts mainly either a `string fileName` (which I don't have and want) or a `System.IO.Stream contentStream`.

So my question is: With a given `byte[]` array is it possible to create the proper `Attachment` object without an intermediary file on disk and what steps do I have to do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert byte[] to [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) and create `Attachment` instance from it. Here is an example:

```
ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
MemoryStream pdf = new MemoryStream(pdfContent);
Attachment data = new Attachment(pdf, ct);
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Just one question: I have just used the constructor with the `name` (of the attached file), not with the `ContentType`, since I have a pure text mail. Is it correct that I only need to specify the `ContentType` if I have a HTML mail?